# Program that can extract something from a website

Tags: extractor

I`m sorry if this is the not right place to ask. If not please delete this.

I`m looking for someone that can help me with a very simple program that can do this:

Login into accounts on an website and extract there a number from every account and and save the details ( account number - the number that must be saved ) on an txt file.

I need this for my job. This program will save me a`lot of time. this is the purpose.

If anybody can help me please let me know. thank you very much.

Comment: If you post code sample (html markup) of the pages and what you want to scrape we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for you, there is ample tooling available.

I will provide you some insight into related tools in the Python ecosystem, since that is what I am most familiar with and also an easy languages for beginners to work with.

If what you are extracting/scraping is relatively simple and doesn't require complex UI interaction with website elements, I would recommend [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) Sessions to retain cookies and additional information for use in a series of authenticated requests, and [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse document trees in order to extract the data you are interested in.

For more complex interaction, you will need to look towards browser automation and possibly more advanced scraping frameworks. Hopefully I've given you enough keywords to go far in Google.

Of course, you'll need to first learn the basics of programming and how web data is structured if you want to write scripts like this. That is left to you to learn and absorb.